# rbenv install 2.7.1 fails on Mac OS Catalina using home-brew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, macos-catalina, rbenv

I have been trying to install ruby for a few days now.

I installed home-brew checked that openssl@1.1 was installed.

I ran `brew install rbenv` and congfigure my zsh as follows,

```
local READLINE_PATH=$(brew --prefix readline)
local OPENSSL_PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl)
export LDFLAGS="-L$READLINE_PATH/lib -L$OPENSSL_PATH/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$READLINE_PATH/include -I$OPENSSL_PATH/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$READLINE_PATH/lib/pkgconfig:$OPENSSL_PATH/lib/pkgconfig"

# Use the OpenSSL from Homebrew instead of ruby-build
# Note: the Homebrew version gets updated, the ruby-build version doesn't
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$OPENSSL_PATH"

# Place openssl@1.1 at the beginning of your PATH (preempt system libs)
export PATH=$OPENSSL_PATH/bin:$PATH

# Load rbenv
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

# Extract the latest version of Ruby so you can do this:
# rbenv install $LATEST_RUBY_VERSION
export LATEST_RUBY_VERSION=$(rbenv install -l | grep -v - | tail -1)
```

When I try to run `rbenv install 2.7.1` I get a build error. Saying it can't require openssl@1.1.

I checked it is installed and tried everything I can think of. This was tested on catalina 10.15 fresh install.
I reformatted my computer and installed the Xcode command tools as well.

Here are the logs.

```
installing manpages:                /Users/main/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/share/man (man1, man5)
installing default gems from lib:   /Users/main/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0 (build_info, cache, doc, extensions, gems, specifications)
                                    benchmark 0.1.0
/private/var/folders/cv/z8f4fy9171z64hl8vk4ms68h0000gn/T/ruby-build.20200617194325.10220.l3muIu/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
        from /private/var/folders/cv/z8f4fy9171z64hl8vk4ms68h0000gn/T/ruby-build.20200617194325.10220.l3muIu/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
        from /private/var/folders/cv/z8f4fy9171z64hl8vk4ms68h0000gn/T/ruby-build.20200617194325.10220.l3muIu/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/specification.rb:2426:in `to_ruby'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:846:in `block (2 levels) in install_default_gem'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:279:in `open_for_install'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:845:in `block in install_default_gem'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in `each'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in `install_default_gem'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:799:in `block in <main>'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:950:in `block in <main>'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in `each'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-all] Error 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated I am getting pretty annoyed.

Comment: Have you tried `brew install openssl`? I have faced similar problems in the past (it is very frustrating) with rvm, and found that `rvm install 2.6.5 --with-openssl-dir=\`brew --prefix openssl\`` did the trick. Not sure if there is anything similar with rbenv

Comment: Yeah I have. For whatever reason openssl for ruby fails to build and I can't figure out why. It saids failed to build openssl when doing rbenv install version. I am wondering if I am missing a dependency on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was I installed the entire Xcode package found online instead of through the App Store. Doing this helped solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

ruby-build will try its best to download and compile the wanted Ruby version, but sometimes compilation fails because of unmet system dependencies, or compilation succeeds but the new Ruby version exhibits weird failures at runtime. The following instructions are our recommendations for a sane build environment.

macOS:
If you haven't done so, install Xcode Command Line Tools (xcode-select --install) and Homebrew. Then:

#### optional, but recommended:

`brew install openssl readline`

#### use Homebrew OpenSSL (note: will not work for ruby < 2.4)

```
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"
rbenv install 2.6.5
```